# SPFx web part to get data from Azure AD - Getting some values but not others

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I have an SPFx web part and I wish to display the users within a group.
I am trying to get their Display Name and other data (Email) but I get null for their Display Name.
I do get data for their ID (GUID).
thanks
P
(also including some warnings I get)

```
protected async getGroupData(): Promise<string> {
    console.log('getGroupData...');

    //const { context } = this.props;
    const client: MSGraphClientV3 = await this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient("3");
    const theADUsers: any = await client.api(`/groups/${"group guid"}/members/microsoft.graph.user`)
      .header('ConsistencyLevel', 'eventual')
      //.search('displayName:P')
      .select('displayName,id,mail,surname')
      .orderby('displayName')
      .get();

    console.log(theADUsers);

    return ""
}
```

> odata.context :
> "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(displayName,id,mail,surname)"
> value :  Array(15) 0 :  displayName :  null id :  "4d76a6e0-etc" mail
> :  null surname :  null
>
> Warning - lint - src/webparts/v2Test/V2TestWebPart.ts(8,10): error
> @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars: 'escape' is defined but never used.
> Warning - lint - src/webparts/v2Test/V2TestWebPart.ts(50,18): error
> @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any: Unexpected any. Specify a
> different type. Warning - lint -
> src/webparts/v2Test/V2TestWebPart.ts(53,5): error prefer-const:
> 'stringToReturn' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead. Warning -
> lint - src/webparts/v2Test/V2TestWebPart.ts(72,23): error
> @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any: Unexpected any. Specify a
> different type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to request the **User.ReadBasic.All** or **User.Read.All** permission to see the user profile properties.

Using the Graph Explorer, I first tried to get Group members with just **Group.Read.All**. This was the response:

[image]

I then added the **User.ReadBasic.All** permission and this was the response:

[image]

Finally I added the **User.Read.All** permission and I got back the full profile:

[image]

For SharePoint Framework, you need to make the permission requests in **config/package-solution.json**

[image]

You then need to bundle an package the solution and deploy it to the app catalog.

You then need to go to the **API access** page in the SharePoint Admin Center and approve the permission requests.

[image]

Once these steps are complete, you can use `MSGraphClientV3` to make calls to the Microsoft Graph. Here's the `render()` method from asimple example.

```
import { MSGraphClientV3 } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import * as MicrosoftGraph from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types';

// ...

public render(): void {
  this.domElement.innerHTML = `
  <section class="${styles.helloGraph} ${!!this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams ? styles.teams : ''}">
    <div class="${styles.welcome}">
      <img alt="" src="${this._isDarkTheme ? require('./assets/welcome-dark.png') : require('./assets/welcome-light.png')}" class="${styles.welcomeImage}" />
      <h2>Well done, ${escape(this.context.pageContext.user.displayName)}!</h2>
      <div>${this._environmentMessage}</div>
      <div>Web part property value: <strong>${escape(this.properties.description)}</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Group Members:</h3>
      <div id="membersContainer"></div>
    </div>
  </section>`;      

  this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3')
    .then((client: MSGraphClientV3): void => {
      client.api('groups/46b50021-065a-44d3-9a9b-f2fa08084a38/members')
      .get((error: any, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
        const members: MicrosoftGraph.User[] = response.value;
        const elem: Element = this.domElement.querySelector("#membersContainer");
        elem.innerHTML = members.map((member) => {
          return `<span>${member.displayName} (${member.mail})</span>`;
        }).join(`<br />`);
      });
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rob. Do you know where in my SPFx I have to add that?

Comment: You add permission requests in the **config/package-solution.json** file and you consent those permission requests in the SharePoint Admin Center after you deploy the package to the app catalog. See the two units on calling the Microsoft Graph in the **Use Microsoft Graph & third-party APIs** Microsoft Learn module (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/sharepoint-spfx-graph-3rd-party-apis/) for more details. Please note that this module has not yet been updated to use `MSGraphClientV3` so the code may not work exactly as shown.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I tried that and still just getting the GUID. My package-soluution.json now contains ... "webApiPermissionRequests": [ 
        { 
          "resource": "Microsoft Graph", 
          "scope": "Group.Read.All" 
        },
        { 
          "resource": "Microsoft Graph", 
          "scope": "User.ReadBasic.All" 
        } ,
        { 
          "resource": "Microsoft Graph", 
          "scope": "User.Read.All" 
        }  
    ],

Comment: And I approved the requests in the Admin center

Comment: I just built a sample SPFx web part and things are working as expected. I updated my answer with the basics. Can you try running your code again? Maybe do a hard reload (CTRL +F5) to ensure caching isn't an issue.